# extraño distinct para hacer un ranking

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo un problema haciendo un ranking en sql con las siguientes restricciones:

`x y z
1 1 8
1 2 9
2 1 9
2 2 4
3 1 5
3 2 3
3 3 1`

el resultado debe ser el siguiente

`x y z
1 2 9
2 1 9
3 3 1`

las restricciones son las siguientes

la columna x debe ser distinct y la columna 2 debe ser distintc y la columna z es la que da la prioridad. Esto quiere decir que ni en la columna x y la columna y deben no haber valores repetidos.

se forma secuencial sería se la siguiente manera
seleccionamos la tupla (1,2,9) ya que es la primera con el valor de z más grande.
Eliminamos todos los que compartan la columna x y la columna y con esa seleccion, por lo que nos queda:

`x y z
2 1 9
3 1 5
3 3 1`

luego seleccionamos (2,1,9) ya que es el que queda con mayor z, nuevamente eliminamos las filas que comparten la columna x o la columna y.

`x y z
3 3 1`

finalmente nos quedamos con la tupla (3,3,1).

De forma secuencial es simple pero extremadamente ineficiente de hacer en sql. La pregunta es ¿existe una forma se hacerlo en una sola query en sql?

saludos y muchas gracias

Comment: Sql es matematica de conjuntos, y aunque hay una logica en lo que planteas, el paso siguiente depende siempre del resultado anterior, por lo cual no veo una forma de hacerlo en sql. solo como referencia (ya que sos un usuario experto en la red), mira el [tour]

Comment: Alguna posibilidad que puedas usar algún otro motor de base de datos?

Comment: @Lamak : si, estoy usando hive

Answer (score 2):

Yo opto primero por obtener una tabla ordenada por la columna `z` y añadiendo a los resultados una columna de orden `row_number` a la que llamo `b`.

Hecho esto agrupo esta tabla `b` por la columna `y` y ordenandola descendentemente por la columna `z` que en este caso se mantiene en el orden ascendente de la columna `row_number`

```
   select x, y , z from(
    select @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number, t.* from tabla t
      JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
      order by z desc
    )b group by y order by row_number asc
```

**EDITO:**

Si no se quisiera usar cursores, habria que ordenadorlo por `z` y `x`, suponiendo que la columna `x` es una columna de índices, por lo tanto el mayor valor en `z` estará en el menor valor de `x` cuando hubiesen valores iguales

```
 select x, y , z from(
    select * from tabla 
      order by z desc
    )b group by y
    order by z desc, x asc
```

Comment: excelente. Funciona según lo solicitado por el usuario, +1. (acá un link a una [demo de tu código](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9be170/30))

Comment: El problema es que estás usando cursores y eso no es del sql estandar.

Comment: select x, y , z from(
    select * from tabla 
      order by z desc
    )b group by y
    order by z desc, x asc

creo que falta alguna función de agregación?

Comment: se entendió que falta una función de agregación? muchas gracias

Comment: acá un ejemplo, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3b86d/1 : no cumple con el requerimiento inicial porque como se ve, la fila 1 y la fila 2 tienen por x=1, y uno de los requerimientos iniciales es que cada columna por separado sea distinct. saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: Se presentan problemas para cumplir con todos los requisitos, por ejemplo, que pasaria si el valor maximo de z está en la fila 3-2-10?, si eso sucede la combinacion del valor 3 para y no existiria ya que hemos usado el 3 para x, deberia devolver solo 2 filas en este caso? otra pregunta es, se debe dar por hecho que x e y siempre seran los mismos,  otra, se da por hecho que habran tantos valores distintos en x e y? siendo en este caso 3 para 3?